# Does microsoft admin consent for azure active directory take time to propagate?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are trying to call school data from Azure Active Directory using Microsoft Graph API. For our scopes, an Admin would give consent for our application.

We then refresh the `access token` for the user which shows correct scopes, 
but when tried to make an API call as soon as the Admin provides the required consent, it results in an error with error code `Authorization_RequestDenied`. 
After couple of minutes, this works fine.

Is this normal or am I doing anything wrong

Comment: It should be almost instant. If you re-authenticate rather than simply refreshing the token, does that change the behavior?

Comment: No, re-authenticating user doesn't change the behavior

Comment: Can you provide more details in your question please?  We need the client-request-id and timestamp for the first request (that gets access denied) and for the later request that works.  Chances are that you are hitting a replication delay or some authorization caching, but won't know for sure until we get more details.